# Create dynamic variables in Jinja2

Tags: jinja2

I'm trying to create router configs automatically with Ansible and a Jinja2 template. My vars are in two different files: one valid for all routers (all.yml) and an additional one per router (router.yml). I'd like to create a variable to look up the IP address in the router.yml but it seems I can get it right:

all.yml:

```
vlans:
- { id: 2001, name: TRUSTED-NET }
- { id: 2002, name: UNTRUSTED-NET }
```

router.yml:

```
2001_ip: 10.200.2.1 255.255.255.0
2002_ip: 10.168.28.1 255.255.255.0
```

makeconfig.j2

```
{% for vlan in vlans %}
 interface Vlan{{ vlan.id }}
  description {{ vlan.name }}
  ip address {{ vlan.ip+'_ip' }} -> TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'str'
  ip address {{ vlan.id|string+'_ip' }} -> output is: ip address 2001_ip
```

How do I have to specify the variable correctly in order to replace it with the value from router.yml?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the classic dictionary key access in Jinja as well, e.g. `router[vlan.id ~ '_ip']`. The [tilde operator](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/3.0.x/templates/#other-operators) is for string concatenation.

```
{% set vlans = [{'id': 2001, 'name': 'LAN 1'},
                {'id': 2002, 'name': 'LAN 1'}] %}
{% set router = {'2001_ip': '10.200.2.1 255.255.255.0',
                 '2002_ip': '10.168.28.1 255.255.255.0'} %}

{% for vlan in vlans %}
 interface Vlan{{ vlan.id }}
  description {{ vlan.name }}
  ip address {{ router[vlan.id ~ '_ip'] }}
{% endfor %}
```

Output:

```
 interface Vlan2001
  description LAN 1
  ip address 10.200.2.1 255.255.255.0

 interface Vlan2002
  description LAN 1
  ip address 10.168.28.1 255.255.255.0
```